# Finding who uploaded an S3 file

Tags: amazon-s3

How do you identify which IAM user uploaded a file to an S3 bucket? I can see properties like 'last modified', but not the IAM user.

For my use case, I can't add random metadata because the file is being uploaded by Cyberduck.

Comment: This is a server administration question, not programming. Please ask for it to be migrated to a more appropriate site, like serverfault.com.

Comment: Did you ever answer this question? I need to know who to email once a lambda trigger on an s3 putObject operation completes.

Comment: Why not just use cloudtrail?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at S3 server access logging? I believe the logs will include the canonical user ID of the uploader, unless anonymous. Not quite sure how you turn that into an IAM access key, but perhaps there's a way.

Or you could look at CloudTrail logs (assuming that you have CloudTrail enabled). They should show you the access key used to perform the upload.

Or I guess you could set up different upload locations, one per authorized IAM user, and then add appropriate policies so that only user X could upload to his specific location.

[Added] You might also want to specify a bucket policy that requires uploaders to give you, the bucket owner, full control of the object. Then you can query the ACLs of the object and determine the owner (which will be the original uploader).

Answer (score 0):

You can try hit the [`Get Bucket` REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) programmatically or with something like `curl`. The `Contents > Owner > DisplayName` key might be what you're looking for.

Sample response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <Name>bucket</Name>
    <Prefix/>
    <Marker/>
    <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
    <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
    <Contents>
      <Key>my-image.jpg</Key>
      <LastModified>2009-10-12T17:50:30.000Z</LastModified>
      <ETag>&quot;fba9dede5f27731c9771645a39863328&quot;</ETag>
      <Size>434234</Size>
      <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
      <Owner>                           
        <ID>75aa57f09aa0c8caeab4f8c24e99d10f8e7faeebf76c078efc7c6caea54ba06a</ID>
        <DisplayName>mtd@amazon.com</DisplayName>
      </Owner>
    </Contents>
</ListBucketResult>
```

Comment: Hi is ther any CLI to get who uploaded an S3 file

Answer (score 0):

If the file to the S3 bucket is uploaded by POST operation and you can grab the details information using Amazon Athena > Query editor. The query would look like this:

```
SELECT bucketowner, Requester, RemoteIP, Operation, Key, HTTPStatus, ErrorCode, RequestDateTime
FROM "databasename"."tablename"
WHERE (Operation='REST.PUT.OBJECT' OR Operation = 'REST.POST.UPLOAD')
AND parse_datetime(RequestDateTime,'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z')
BETWEEN parse_datetime('2021-11-11:00:42:42','yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss')
AND parse_datetime('2021-12-31:00:42:42','yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss')
AND Requester='arn:aws:sts::accoint-number::assumed-role/ROLE-NAME/email'
```

For more information on [athena](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/)